# Adobe and Firebase Not working in AppDelegate at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, appdelegate, adobe-analytics

I implemented Adobe Lifecycle events and Firebase messaging feature in AppDelegate in two different projects.

But when I try to add adobe lifecycle code with firebase code and import the pods for Adobe Analytics (AEPCore ,AEPAnalytics ,AEPUserProfile, AEPIdentity, AEPLifecycle, AEPSignal,AEPServices ,ACPCore) then I get this error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'AppDelegate' to type 'MessagingDelegate?'

Please help if someone faced this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when you write " extension AppDelegate: FirebaseMessaging.MessagingDelegate " instead of "extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate"